# String literals as char arrays

Tags: c++

Is it considered bad practice to pass string literals as char*, when an array and not a c-string is expected by the function? From my code:

```
char ConsoleIO::GetNextChar(string prompt, char* choices, int numChoices) {
    // Loop until valid input, or 10 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Write(prompt);

        char* buffer = new char[200];
        cin.getline(buffer, 200);
        char choice = tolower(buffer[0]);

        if (in(choice, choices, numChoices)) {
            return choice;
        }

        WriteLine("Invalid choice.");
    }
    // Just return the first choice as the default.
    return choices[0];
}

// In main:
char userChoice = ConsoleIO::GetNextChar("Make a selection: ", "234", 3);
```

It compiles, but is it bad practice?

Comment: How does this even compile? `"234"` is a `const char[]` which cannot be converted to a `char *`. You should at least get a warning.

Comment: Nope, I don't even get a warning on this. My guess is that since it's not by-ref the constness can be ignored, and char[] and char* are really the same thing in c++, it allows me to pass a const char[] as a char*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a C or C-related programmer sees `char*` they're going to naturally think of passing in a C-string. In my opinion, it's absolutely fine to do that. If you want to invoke an array of characters in C, I'd do it like this:

```
char ConsoleIO::GetNextChar(string prompt, char[] choices, int numChoices)
```

But, you're in C++ so you should use a `std::vector<char>` and then don't pass in `numChoices`, like this:

```
char ConsoleIO::GetNextChar(string prompt, std::vector<char> const& choices)
```

Also, you have a bug. You aren't ever `delete`ing `buffer`, which means it's leaking.

Comment: I appreciate the input, especially on the memory leak. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest use of `std::vector<char> const& choices`.

Comment: @RSahu Excellent point! I'll update it.